# I'm being warned that the Monoid I'm creating is an Orphan Instance. Is there a better way to write this functionality in?

Tags: haskell, anti-patterns, type-systems, algebraic-data-type

```
type PromptSegment = IO (Maybe String)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (IO a) where
  mempty = return mempty
  mappend = liftA2 (<>)
```

This behaves exactly how I want for my purposes.

For example:

```
ghci> let a = return $ Just "hello" :: IO Maybe String
ghci> let b = return $ Just " world" :: IO Maybe String
ghci> let c = return $ Nothing :: IO Maybe String
ghci> a `mappend` b `mappend` c
Just "hello world"
```

However, I'm pretty aware that maybe, for a different Monoid a => Monoid (IO a) instance other than a PromptSegment, maybe I wouldn't want mappend to behave the same way??  I feel like there's better way to do this than creating the orphan monoid instance above.

*Current API design*

```
currentDirectory :: PromptSegment
currentDirectory = Just <$> getCurrentDirectory

main :: IO ()
main = buildMainPrompt
         [ bold . fgColor skyBlue <$> currentDirectory
         ,  (fgColor deepSkyBlue3 . underline . bold <$> gitCurrentBranch)
           <> (fgColor defaultDarkGreen . bold <$> gitRepositorySymbol "±")
           <> gitStatusSegment
         ]
         (fgColor red0 . bold <$> makePromptSegment " ➢ ")
         (fgColor slateBlue0 . bold <$> makePromptSegment " λ» ")

gitStatusSegment :: PromptSegment
gitStatusSegment =
  let unstagedSymbol = fgColor gold1 <$> gitUnstagedSymbol "✚"
      stagedSymbol   = fgColor orange <$> gitStagedSymbol "✎"
      pushSymbol     = fgColor red1 . bold <$> gitPushSymbol "↑"
  in prependSpace <$> unstagedSymbol <> stagedSymbol <> pushSymbol
```

This is, of course, a work in progress, but the aim of the program is to create a DSL for defining cli prompt themes (starting with ZSH).This last code sample is mostly to serve the purpose of providing context to the question for why I would want to make IO (Maybe String) a Monoid.  I'm wide open to harsh criticism - especially since this is my first attempt at writing a 'real' program in Haskell.

Comment: I'm afraid the best solution might be to just expect people to use `liftA2`/`<*>` when they want to do this. It's marginally clearer and avoids orphan instances I guess.

Comment: I'm hesitant to do so because it would make the main API of the program unnecessarily noisy.  I'll add a code sample of the main API I'm building right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is are reasons behind [warning again orphan instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3079537/1333025). In particular: If we start using orphan instances, modules can become mutually incompatible: What if two modules define two different instances `Monoid (IO a)`? There is no good way to tell which one should be preferred.

Furthermore using orphan instances often leads to bad program design. If you add an orphan instance to a data type, you're *adding* some functionality to the data type. And sooner or later you'll also need to *modify* the functionality, which isn't (by design) possible with Haskell type classes. At this point you either have to refactor your program or start bending the rules add mess up your design. (This is different from the OO world where subclasses are meant to modify some of the functionality of their parents.)

Therefore I'd strongly suggest to create a new data type for your use case. You'll pay a small one-time price for creating aliases for functions you'll use in your project (most likely in a dedicated module), like

```
import qualified System.Directory as D
getCurrentDirectory :: MyDSL FilePath
getCurrentDirectory = --  something wraping D.getCurrentDirectory
```

or more generally define instance `MonadIO MyDSL` and then

```
getCurrentDirectory :: MonadIO FilePath
getCurrentDirectory = liftIO D.getCurrentDirectory
```

But then  your implementation will be completely independent and as your project evolves, nothing will limit you to make the internals of `MyDSL` more complex or add functionality. Moreover, it'll be safe to use as a library in other projects, without the risk of getting conflicting instances.

Such separation is even more important when you're creating a DSL, because in this case you strongly want to separate the language from its internal implementation. Using an existing data type for a DSL is very likely to cause problems, either when implementing it or due to improper usage by its users.

Comment: To make sure I understand this correctly, I should make PromptSegment a new data type instead of just an alias for IO (Maybe String), and then create instances of other algebraic data types like Monoid off of that new data type (as I need them).

Comment: @Josiah Exactly,  that'd be my suggestion. Add other instances as needed, like `Monad`, `Applicative` etc. Extension [GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/deriving.html#newtype-deriving) can save you a lot of work.